# Using the same key in two dictionaries (Python)

Tags: python, hash, dictionary, key

Here's what I have:

```
from pprint import pprint

Names = {}
Prices = {}
Exposure = {}

def AddName():
    company_name = input("Please enter company name: ")
    return company_name

def AddSymbol(company_name):
    stock_symbol = input("Please enter a stock symbol: ")
    Names[stock_symbol] = company_name
    return Names
```

^^ this updates the Names dictionary fine as {symbol:company name}

```
def AddPrices(stock_symbol):
    buy = float(input("Please enter buying price of stock: "))
    sell = float(input("Please enter current price of stock: "))
    Prices[stock_symbol] = buy, sell
    return Prices
```

^^ this generates a TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' - what I want is it to update the Prices  dictionary like {symbol: buy price, sell price, symbol2: buy price, sell price etc..}

```
def printDicts(Names, Prices):
    '''
    For debug purposes, prints out contents of dictionaries
    '''
    print( "Names is now:" )
    pprint(Names)

    print("Prices now:")
    pprint(Prices)



def main():
    company_name = AddName()
    stock_symbol = AddSymbol(company_name)
    AddPrices(stock_symbol)
    printDicts(Names, Prices)

main()
```

Being new to programming I'm not entirely sure how to fix this. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AddSymbol(company_name)` you return the entire `Names` dictionary.  This entire dictionary is then passed into the `AddPrices` function.  `AddPrices` is meant to have a stock symbol passed into it (a `str`) but you're passing a `dict`.  You could modify `AddSymbol` to return `stock_symbol` instead of `Names`.

I would also recommend that your function names be camel-cased, beginning with a lowercase letter and capitalizing the first letter of each word.  This is what most programmers do for consistency and it's good to form good habits.

Comment: excellent! Works perfectly now! Thanks for the information on the way to format my names also.

Answer (score 1):

Your `AddSymbol` returns `Names`, which is dictionary. Dictionary can't be used as dictionary key.

Just use `return stock_symbol` in `AddSymbol`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you meant to return in your `AddSymbol` function is the symbol and not another dictionary? In that case you do:

```
def AddSymbol(company_name):
    stock_symbol = input("Please enter a stock symbol: ")
    Names[stock_symbol] = company_name
    return stock_symbol
```